# LED indicators on Ethernet cables

Tags: ethernet

I'm wondering why LED indicators are not used on patch panels and on keystone jacks.
I already know that usual LED signals are derived from a 16 bits pulsetrain used in the auto-negotiation mechanism of 802.3
Two questions:

- is there a simple circuit (or simple integrated circuit) used to decode that pulsetrain?
- if there is no local power (as is the case with a patch panel), is there a way to get that power from the remote equipment (remote end of each of the 2 connected cables)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Testing what is plugged at the other end of the cable?

Comment: I believe it is specified  LED is controlled directly by the PHY and not through logic on the physical layer signals so ultimately I think what you are asking for , while logical, is not how it is done and not according to 802.3 as far as I am aware

Comment: @bobflux asked: "What are you trying to achieve". My patch p[anel is in a closet. Switches and network devices are elsewhere. To ease diagnostic while I'm in the closet, I would like to see if a network device is connected remotely. Half/full and speed would be helpful.

Comment: Good luck. You need a 8 bit shift register and then you have to derive somehow the clock pulse which is nearly impossible to do at home.

Answer (score 3):

Because patch panels are simply cheap connectors that just connect wires together. They would have to terminate a link from both devices with Ethernet chips to know what speeds they work at. Which is what an Ethernet switch already does.

Answer (score 1):

> My patch p[anel is in a closet. Switches and network devices are elsewhere. To ease diagnostic while I'm in the closet, I would like to see if a network device is connected remotely. Half/full and speed would be helpful

OK, so you need the full functionality of an ethernet PHY including speed negociation. The PHY is the chip that handles the PHYsical layer of ethernet. For example optical and wired ethernet use the same protocol at MAC level and above, but different PHYs. Note the PHY controls the LEDs on the ethernet port.

That pretty much means you need a device with an ethernet port. It would be pointless to replicate that.

The simplest solution is to use any device that will work, like a laptop, a raspberry pi, or a USB-Ethernet dongle connected to the USB port of your mobile phone... and plug the ethernet cable, then watch the LEDs. Plus it has a screen and a GUI so you can even ping what's at the other end, or scan its IP address, so you know what device is at the other end of the cable.